# Retrieving the "reply to" email address using postfix and piping to a file

Tags: postfix

I have been working on a project to receive any email address (whether that email exists or not) sent to a domain, then we have to pipe that email to a .php script for further processing.

I've got Postfix set up to receive any email sent to the domain and it is working correctly.  The configuration is below

My problem is I need to be able to give an email address to our client that doesn't exist on our domain.  The example is "customercompany_customerAccountID@thedomain.com.  We will then receive an email sent to this address, which doesn't exist on our server, but we want to extract out the company name, and the company account ID and match it up with our clients, then send the email to the correct email on their account.

The problem is that email address "customercompany_customerAccountID@thedomain.com" is not found inside the .php script when the script receives the email from the Postfix PIPE process.  I was thinking that there would be a "reply-to" sent over from Postfix which would hold this email address, but if you see my code below and the dump from the email its not there and I don't know where to go from here.

Here is how I configured the Postfix stuff to work:
Created a virtualusertable:

```
@globalvrm.com globalvrm_email
```

Ran

```
postmap /usr/local/etc/postfix/virtusertable
```

To create:

```
virtusertable.db
```

Added the domain to a local-hosts-names file:

```
/usr/local/etc/postfix/local-host-names
globalvrm.com #domain
```

Added the following lines to "/usr/local/etc/postfix/main.cf" :

```
home_mailbox = Maildir/
    mailbox_command =
    virtual_maps = hash:/usr/local/etc/postfix/virtusertable
    mydestination = /usr/local/etc/postfix/local-host-names
```

I'm reading the email from STDIN as follows:

```
function mailRead($iKlimit = "")
    {

            // Set default limit of 1024k if no limit has been specified
            if ($iKlimit == "") {
                $iKlimit = 1024;
            }

            // Error strings
            $sErrorSTDINFail = "Error - failed to read mail from STDIN!";

        // Attempt to connect to STDIN
        $fp = fopen("php://stdin", "r");

        // Failed to connect to STDIN? (shouldn't really happen)
        if (!$fp) {
            echo $sErrorSTDINFail;
            exit();
        }

        // Create empty string for storing message
        $sEmail = "";

        // Read message up until limit (if any)
        if ($iKlimit == -1) {
            while (!feof($fp)) {
                $sEmail .= fread($fp, 1024);
            }                    
        } else {
            while (!feof($fp) && $i_limit < $iKlimit) {
                $sEmail .= fread($fp, 1024);
                $i_limit++;
            }        
        }

        // Close connection to STDIN
        fclose($fp);

        // Return message
        return $sEmail;
    }

    //Read email
    $email = mailRead($iKlimit = "-1");
$xx = print_r($email,true);
```

I tried dumping out the results inside $email, here they are:

```
    From aaron@thedomain.com Sat Mar 30 21:15:57 2019 Received: from alora.out.smtp.thehostdomain.com (alora.out.smtp.thehostdomain.com [209.33.201.216]) by server1.adifferentdomain.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id 50309E60CE for ; Sat, 30 Mar 2019 21:15:57 -0600 (MDT) 
Received: from tdcmail1.thehostdomain.com (tdcmail1.thehostdomain.com [IPv6:2604:2c00:0:103::40]) (using TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 (256/256 bits)) (Client CN "*.thehostdomain.com", Issuer "GeoTrust TLS RSA CA G1" (not verified)) by alora.out.smtp.thehostdomain.com (Postfix) with ESMTPS id 44X0ws0cNMzMyHw for ; Sat, 30 Mar 2019 21:15:57 -0600 (MDT) 
Received: from Sales1 (209-33-199-176-dsl.thehostdomain.net [203.33.333.333]) (using TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 (256/256 bits)) (No client certificate requested) (Authenticated sender: aaron@thedomain.com) by tdcmail1.thehostdomain.com (Postfix) with ESMTPSA id 44X0wr3QMPzMxP1 for ; Sat, 30 Mar 2019 21:15:56 -0600 (MDT) 
From: "Aaron LastNAme" To: Subject: asdf Date: Sat, 30 Mar 2019 21:15:55 -0600 Message-ID: MIME-Version: 1.0 Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="----=_NextPart_000_0536_01D4E73D.C6D95460" X-Mailer: Microsoft Office Outlook 12.0 Thread-Index: AdTncA15uyXIYYirTp2PzuqlPDq6SA== Content-Language: en-us This is a multi-part message in MIME format. ------=_NextPart_000_0536_01D4E73D.C6D95460 Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="----=_NextPart_001_0537_01D4E73D.C6D95460" ------=_NextPart_001_0537_01D4E73D.C6D95460 Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit ffffffff thedomain | Aaron LastNAme toll free: 1.800.222.2222, ext. 501 email: aaron@thedomain.com website: www.thedomain.com https://thedomain.com/graphics/logo.png facebook_email_icon Follow us on Facebook twitter_email_icon Follow us on Twitter CONFIDENTIALITY NOTICE: This e-mail message, including any attachments, is for the sole use of the intended recipients and may contain confidential or proprietary information. Any unauthorized review, use, disclosure or distribution is prohibited. ------=_
NextPart_001_0537_01D4E73D.C6D95460 Content-Type: text/html; charset="us-ascii" Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

I couldnt see anywhere where that "reply-to" email address is found.

How can I obtain this?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by writing out the contents to a .txt file.  When I looked inside that file the email address was in there for the "To:"  I then cat that file inside php and grep out the email address.  Hopefully that helps someone else who has my same problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Reply-to:** header is not mandatory .

If **Reply-to:** is missing you must use **From:** , and in case this is missing you can look for the first line **From**